# Apache wildcard SSL cert for wildcard vhost and specifically named vhost

Tags: php, python, ssl, apache

We are running a PHP site that uses custom subdomains for our customers, so we've implemented a wildcard SSL cert with a wildcard VHost in Apache (version 2.2.3). These subdomain PHP web apps also utilize a reverse proxy to a Pyramid web app behind two URL prefixes for our REST and RPC API.

We also have an admin interface that runs on Pyramid. We would normally simply reverse proxy to the admin interface, but I can't seem to utilize the wildcard SSL cert for both of these virtual hosts. What am I doing wrong?

Here is our vhost config:

```
NameVirtualHost *:443

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias *.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example/current/www
    ErrorLog logs/wild-example.com-SSL-error_log
    CustomLog logs/wild-example.com-SSL-access_log combined
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/star_example.com.2012.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/star_example.com.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/NetworkSolutions_CA.2012.crt
    <Directory /var/www/html/example/current/www>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    ProxyRequests On
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass /restapi/ http://127.0.0.1:6543/restapi/
    ProxyPassReverse /restapi/ http://127.0.0.1:6543/restapi/
    ProxyPass /rpcapi/ http://127.0.0.1:6543/rpcapi/
    ProxyPassReverse /rpcapi/ http://127.0.0.1:6543/rpcapi/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias admin.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example/current/www
    ErrorLog logs/admin-example.com-SSL-error_log
    CustomLog logs/admin-example.com-SSL-access_log combined
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/star_example.com.2012.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/star_example.com.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/NetworkSolutions_CA.2012.crt
    <Directory /var/www/html/example/current/www>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ProxyRequests On
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:6542/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:6542/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: How is it not working? I know from personal experience that Apache is VERY sensitive to the ordering of vhost definitions when you're using wildcards. The wildcarding should generally come LAST in the .conf loading hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting error messages in the ssl_error logs that we can see? You should be able to just copy the main vhost and just set it up as a specific subdomain vhost.

In fact, your original *.example.com thing should just cover any subdomain. I think if you simply specify the new subdomain as a regular port 80 vhost, and then visit the site at https://admin.example.com, it should be protected.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following line:

```
    ServerAlias *.example.com
```

and in the second VirtualHost section, change ServerName:

```
    ServerName admin.example.com
```

The fist *. traps admin.example.com in the first VirtualHost section. You also don't want both of them defining the same VirtualHost (example.com). ServerName needs to be different for each subdomain.